# How do I hide my Electron app window when Mission Control is launched?

Tags: macos, electron

I'm building an Electron app and I don't want my app to appear in macOS Mission Control. Is there a way to hide the window when Mission Control is launched?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to implement this behavior by using the `setAlwaysOnTop` method on the window object.

```
window.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
```

MacOS by default do not show windows with this property in Mission Control.

For more information about this method see the Electron documentation: https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#winsetalwaysontopflag-level-relativelevel

Comment: it doesn't work after the electron version >= 8.x. but it works on <= 7.x, I just test 7.x 6.x 5.x

Answer (score 1):

In Electron 23.0.0 [it was added new win.setHiddenInMissionControl API](https://www.electronjs.org/blog/electron-23-0#new-features) to allow developers to opt out of Mission Control on macOS.

Also you could [set it with new window options](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/browser-window#new-browserwindowoptions):

```
hiddenInMissionControl boolean (optional) macOS 
Whether window should be hidden when the user toggles into mission control.
```