# Hide electron window on macOs Mission Control

Tags: javascript, macos, electron

Well, I have an electron application that is only showing up when the user clicks on the Tray icon, but when I use mission control view on macOS it is also showing my app when it's opened, but I'd like to hide it.

I've already found this solution:

```
win.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
```

but it's only working on older versions of the electron.

Has anyone found another solution for this problem? Thanks for all of your help!

Comment: Possibly here is the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75661699/4940366